# Serialise non string values to JSON

Tags: javascript, json, serialization

I have a javascript object that includes a number of integer properties as well as Date values and an integer array. Whenever I call JSON.stringify(entityModel, null, 2) on the object and pass the result to an HTTP Handler I end up with something like this:

```
{
 "UserId": "12345",
 "Name": "Stewart",
 "PositionId": "2",
 "NextBirthday": "10-11-2013",
 "FavouriteColour": "Blue",
 "Hobbies": "1,3" // this is an array of ints in the client object prior to stringificaiton
}
```

When what I want is

```
{
 "UserId": 12345,
 "Name": "Stewart",
 "PositionId": 2,
 "NextBirthday": "10-11-2013",
 "FavouriteColour": "Blue",
 "Hobbies": [1,3]
}
```

I'm new to JSON, but can someone please tell me where Im going wrong? Basically on the server side my deserializer wont deserialise the Hobbies property to an integer array and will potentially have issues with the integers when they are being treated as strings by JSON.

## EDIT

When the page laods my client object is thus:

```
function EntityModel(){
   this.UserId = null;
   this.Name = null;
   this.PositionId = null;
   this.NextBirthday = null;
   this.FavouriteColour = null;
   this.Hobbies = null;
}
```

I then assign values to it, checking if the value is a number and assigning an integer value using parseInt where appropriate. For the Hobbies property I assign an integer array as below:

```
var checkedValues = new Array();
element.find("input[type=checkbox]:checked").each(function () {
   checkedValues.push(parseInt($(this).val()));
});
return checkedValues;
```

So my object should finally look something like this

```
function EntityModel(){
   this.UserId = 123;
   this.Name = "Stewart";
   this.PositionId = 2;
   this.NextBirthday = '10-11-2013';
   this.FavouriteColour = 'blue';
   this.Hobbies = [1,2];
}
```

I then pass object to handler as below:

```
var json = JSON.stringify(entityModel, null, 2);
$.ajax({
  url: handlerPath,
  contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
  type: 'POST',
  dataType: "json",
  data: json,
  success: OnComplete,
  error: OnFail
});
```

Finally on the handler side I retrieve the JSON string

```
using (StreamReader inputStream = new StreamReader(      HttpContext.Current.Request.InputStream ))
{
   jsonString = inputStream.ReadToEnd();
}
```

And it looks like this

```
"{\n  \"UserId\": \"12345\",\n  \"Name\": \"Stewart\",\n  \"PositionId\": \"2\",\n  \"NextBirthday\": \"2013-11-10\",\n  \"FavouriteColour\": \"Blue\",\n  \"Hobbies\": \"1,2,3\"\n}"
```

# EDIT 2

Here are the functions I am using to give values to my client object. The first function either returns an integer array (if the value is based on checkbox list selection) or an int (if value is a number) or a string

```
function getElemValue(element, elementType, targetType) {
        switch (elementType) {
            case "System.Web.UI.WebControls.CheckBoxList":
                var checkedValues = new Array();
                element.find("input[type=checkbox]:checked").each(function () {
                    checkedValues.push(parseInt($(this).val()));
                });
                return checkedValues;
            default:
                return TryParseInt(element.val());   
        }
    }

    function TryParseInt(str) {
        var retValue = str;
        if (str != null) {
            if (str.length > 0) {
                if (!isNaN(str)) {
                    retValue = parseInt(str);
                }
            }
        }
        return retValue; 
    }
```

Comment: Do you really have arrays? Or do you have some custom array-like data structure?

Comment: I cannot reproduce it (http://jsfiddle.net/FWNRe/), which means that you don't have numbers or arrays like you think you have. Fix the original data structure and you will get the JSON you want.

Comment: What does `console.log(entityModel)` output?

Comment: After looking at @FelixKling's comment, if your original data structure is correct then check you're not importing a badly written shim for the JSON object.

Comment: Edited Original Q with more info about how I am producing client object before Stringifying. The vaklues should be getting treated as integers and an array

Comment: "I then assign values to it, checking if the value is a number and assigning an integer value using parseInt where appropriate." Could you post **that** code?  It’s one of the most relevant bits in this situation...

Comment: See Edit 2 in original Q

Comment: As Marcel already said, could you do a `console.log(entityModel)` *just before* you make the call to `JSON.stringify`? Do you still see an array or is it a string?

Comment: console.log is tellng me that the values are indeed all strings. The question I have now then is why? And how can I ensure they are treated as correct type?

Comment: Then there must be a problem when you assign the values to the properties or pre-process the data. There is not much we can do though, because we cannot run your code. If you don't know about it yet, learn how to use your browsers developer tools (have a look at this [tutorial](http://www.netmagazine.com/tutorials/javascript-debugging-beginners)) to debug JS code. Set breakpoints in your code and track how each value is created/processed. This usually reveals pretty quickly where the problem is.

Comment: Ok, but in theory, should a value that is first null and then equal to parseInt("1") not be an integer? Equally a value that is first null and then equal to new array() not be an array?

Answer (score 0):

I get the impression that the function `getElementValue` doesn't quite do what you think it does.

Here’s a few (potential) problems I see:

- is the `element` argument a jQuery object? If not, `element.val()` is probably going to throw an exception.  Does the browser's console show any errors?
- you're using `parseInt` without a second argument (the radix); this means that if the string starts with a zero (`0`), it will be interpreted as an **octal** number.  To prevent that, use `parseInt(str, 10)` (or `Number(str)`, but that will accept floating-point numners as well).
- your function `TryParseInt` looks needlessly complex. It should be enough to do a `parseInt(str, 10)`, and if that yields `NaN`, return the original string instead.

For example:

```
function tryParseInt(str) {
    var retValue = parseInt(str, 10);
    return isNaN(retValue) ? str : retValue;
}
```

And finally: all I see here is assigning some values to a `checkedValues` array, but nothing to an `EntityModel` object.  So we're still missing the final assignment — and I’ve a hunch that's exactly where it goes wrong, and everything gets converted to strings.